# Can I use Micronaut thymeleaf views from a external folder

Tags: java, thymeleaf, micronaut

I want to use .html view files located in a folder in the same directory as the jar. I managed to do this with static resources but I haven't had any luck with views using thymeleaf or any other template engine.

I tried doing something like this inside of my application.yml:
`micronaut: views: folder: "file:frontend"`

Is it even possible to load views from a external folder other then the resources folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I believe you are going to use e.g. React with Micronaut. You can use the below config with Micronaut. You will also need `maven-resources-plugin` and e.g. `frontend-maven-plugin` as well.

[This repo](https://github.com/roar-skinderviken/micronaut-plus-react) contains a Micronaut 4.0.1 example-app with the required config along with a very basic React app.

Disclosure: I'm the owner of the linked Github repo.

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronaut-plus-react

  views:
    folder: static

  router:
    static-resources:
      default:
        enabled: true
        mapping: /**/*
        paths:
          - classpath:static
```

You will need a controller like this to serve requests for your SPA-app.

```
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.views.View;

@Controller("/")
public class ViewsController {

    @View("index")
    @Get
    public HttpResponse<?> index() {
        return HttpResponse.ok();
    }
}
```

Example config, `frontend-maven-plugin`. Runs the npm-targets.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.4</version>

    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/vite-project</workingDirectory>
        <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
        <nodeVersion>v19.0.0</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>8.19.2</npmVersion>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm ci</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>ci</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>npx vitest</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npx</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>vitest run</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Example config, `maven-resources-plugin`.

`${frontend-src-dir}`
can be defined as `<frontend-src-dir>${project.basedir}/src/main/vite-project</frontend-src-dir>`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>position-react-build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${frontend-src-dir}/dist</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After running `mvn clean install`, your target folder should look like this when using the example repo:

[image]

Comment: I'm having some trouble setting this up. I'm not planning on using react with micronaut. I just have a simple html. css and js website. Currently I'm accessing all the website frontend files from the static resources folder that is in the frontend folder that gets created when you run the .jar file for the first time. I would like to use views so that I can access the html files without the .html extension. I believe this solution still only works for files inside of the resources folder and not files that are able to be changed after build. Am I wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Added a screen-shot that may clarify. As you can see, the SPA-app ends up under target/classes/static. I never tried the case where files are going to change after build, sorry. BR